# Importing wrapped headers into SAS using the libname engine

Tags: sas

I'm trying to import an xlsx file with wrapped headers into SAS. Each header is wrapped across 2 lines, for example:

Att1
Store

I'm using the SAS xl libname engine but I'm only picking up 'Att1' and I'm unable to make any changes to the file prior to import.

Does anyone know of any options or solutions for this?

Many thanks,
Cammie

Comment: What to _you_ mean by _"wrapped"_? Do you mean the headers span accross multiple rows? Or are Att1 and Store in the same cell separated by a "new line" character? _Actual_ wrapped cells or just a visual feature in excel and would not affect importing.

Comment: I mean the second - Att1 and Store are in the same cell and separated by a 'new line' character. Many thanks.

Comment: I tested this with both a `libname` statement and an `import` procedure and the header is imported as-is, including both words _and_ the 'new line' character. We would need more information about your process in order to understand what goes wrong on your end. As Tom suggested, you may want to check if you do not also have a bunch of spaces between the two words, making the whole header more than 32 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with "wrapped" lines from an excel.

That means the 2 lines in one cell are separated with a CRLF (carriedge return) character.

```
%let path=H:\desktop\XLSX\wrapped.xlsx;

        PROC IMPORT
            datafile="&Path"
            out=WORK.wrapped
            DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
            RANGE="Sheet1$A1:0";
            GETNAMES=YES;
        RUN;
```

I got only one line in the header (because the total length was not respecting 32 characters).
In the LABEL you can see the 2 lines.

```
proc sql;
        select memname,
         name,
         label
  from   dictionary.columns
  where  libname = 'WORK'
     and memname = 'WRAPPED';
 quit;
```

So I guess it should be possible to rename your column name with the label and trying to delete the CRLF characters.

```
proc sql;
        select label into: label separated by '|'
  from   dictionary.columns
  where  libname = 'WORK'
     and memname = 'WRAPPED';
 quit;
%put label=&label;
```

But if the name of the column is greater than 32 characters, it will be not possible to rename your column with the two lines.

I suggest you to check if the length of your header, the engine(XLSX).

Because I did a second test with "wrapped" header and length less than 32 characters and the header in the output dataset is correctly imported.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel to what I said in my comment, here's a couple possible workarounds.

If your headers do not have a length of more than 32  characters, you could just set `options validvarname=V7;` before importing or executing assigning your library. This will convert any characters other than alphanumeric characters and unerscores to underscores. Your resulting header should then look like `Att1__Store`.

If however your headers *are* longer than 32 characters. You could work around it as follows. In this example, I created an XLSX workbook with just the value `Att1                        Store` in cell A1, with a new line before `Store`.

First you would import the file without getting column names from the first record of your XLSX file by setting the `GETNAMES` option to `NO` in `proc import`.

```
proc import datafile="<path_to_file>\book1.xlsx" dbms=xlsx out=table replace;
sheet='Sheet1';
getnames=no;
run;
```

The resulting dataset will contain your excel headers in the first observation. Your dataset variables will be named A, B, C, etc... In my case, the `table` dataset has one variable called `A` and one observation with the name of the header, including spaces and new line characters.

Then, you will assign your headers to macro variables after having cleaned them of "invalid" SAS variable name characters:

```
data _null_;
set table;
if _n_=1 then call symput('A',compress(A,,'S'));
stop;
run;
```

Lastly, you will recreate your dataset by renaming each variable to the SAS-valid version of the excel headers as stored in your macro variables and start reading observations from the second row.

```
data table;
set table(rename=(A=&A.) firstobs=2);
run;
```

The resulting dataset has one variable called `Att1Store`.